# Getting the count of some string combination according to the timestamp in linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep, centos, cut

Sorry if the topic is not much clear, Below I'll try to explain my requirement.
I have some logs(actually CDR logs) printing every 15 minutes on my server. in the logs there CDR(lets say it has some  20 or so fields separated by commas). In the cDRs the time stamp also prints. Below is a sample cdr,

```
20-06-17 10:18:15,1637595323095*33659193263131331794958977243262t31,IVR,*886,724134931,1903-2-1|1901-2-0|1917-5-0|1902-2-0|1908-2-0|1911-5-0|,20-06-17 10:18:16,224,1902-2-0|1908-2-0,,
```

I was using below command to get the hourly count of these print lines,

```
cat logfile |grep -a "*886" | cut -d "," -f1 |cut -d ":" -f1 |sort -n |uniq -c
```

result was as below.

```
18 20-06-14 05
112 20-06-14 06
219 20-06-14 07
279 20-06-14 08
326 20-06-14 09
324 20-06-14 10
271 20-06-14 11
257 20-06-14 12
```

Now I happened to need to get the count by every 15 mins, Is there an easy way to get that done ?

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Edited for you, please add 4 spaces at the left to do code blocks next time

Answer (score 0):

First, [useless use of cat](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/#:~:text=If%20you're%20reasonably%20confident,used%20the%20cat%20command%20unnecessarily.). One pointless process removed.

Second, `grep/cut/cut` can all be replaced with a single `sed` or `awk`. Four processes now down to one.

Third - I assume you are reading a log file, and the first field is the timestamp, so... wouldn't they already be in the proper order??? Does it not work correctly without the `sort`? Try it. If it's needed, leave it, but I suspect it might not be, which is another process removed. Sorts can be expensive.

So at best:

```
 sed -nE '/,*886,/{ s/^([0-9-]{8} [[0-9]{2}):.*/\1/; p; }' file | uniq -c
```

This should be faster. Now put it into a [crontab](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux).

```
*/15 * * * * sed -nE '/,*886,/{ s/^([0-9-]{8} [[0-9]{2}):.*/\1/; p; }' /path/to/logfile | uniq -c >| /path/to/report.tmp; mv /path/to/report.tmp /path/to/report;
```

This should recreate your report every 15m.